# Build a dictionary containing for each keys, a set of associate values from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
list = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(0,8),(0,9),(0,1),(3,6),(3,7)]
```

I want to build a dictionary with sets of associate values like this:

```
result = {1:{2,3,5},0:{8,9,1},3:{6,7}}
```

I have this code:

```
return {x:y for (x,y) in list}

result = {1: 5, 0: 1, 3: 7}
```

But I have only the last value, I want all associate values in a set.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

defaultdict could add value for a key without checking existence

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(0,8),(0,9),(0,1),(3,6),(3,7)]
result = defaultdict(list)
for item in mylist:
    result[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help u:

```
lst = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(0,8),(0,9),(0,1),(3,6),(3,7)]
result= {}

[result.setdefault(x, set()).add(y) for x,y in lst]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{1: {2, 3, 5}, 0: {8, 9, 1}, 3: {6, 7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

This code snippet should solve your problem statement:

```
lst = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(0,8),(0,9),(0,1),(3,6),(3,7)]

output_dict = dict()
[output_dict[t[0]].add(t[1]) if t[0] in list(output_dict.keys()) else output_dict.update({t[0]: {t[1]}}) for t in lst]
print(output_dict)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{1: {2, 3, 5}, 0: {8, 9, 1}, 3: {6, 7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you want one liner:

```
In [10]: original_list = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(0,8),(0,9),(0,1),(3,6),(3,7),(1,2)]

In [11]: {x: {r for(q, r) in original_list if q == x} for (x, y) in original_list}
Out[11]: {1: {2, 3, 5}, 0: {1, 8, 9}, 3: {6, 7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
result = {}

for x, y in list:
    if x not in result:
        result[x] = []
    result[x].append(y)

print(result)
```